# Move from subdomain to folder on domain - htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress-blog with all the blogposts listed as this in terms of URL-structure:

`no.blog.domain.com/blogpost`

Now I'm moving all the blogposts to `domain.com/folder/blogpost`

How do I write a regex-rule that let's me 301 redirect all the blogposts to the correct place on the new domain?

All URLs after the last / of the blogposts remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use this following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^no.blog.no\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: is this for the .htaccess-code placed under domain.com webserver?

And what if I have multiple subdomains and just want to redirect no.blog.no, would that do this?

Comment: @user3374110 I've updated the answer for your case. You can change the subdomain part to match yours.

Comment: Thank you so much!! - lastly, should this be placed in .htaccess file on domain.com-server or no.blog.domain.com-server if they are hosted on seperated services